# Is it possible to encrypt WiFi connection?

Tags: encryption, wifi

Is it possible to encrypt (encrypt traffic) WiFi connection from my laptop to my router?
If anyone of you did it?

How I can do this?

Comment: Search for the WPA2 option in your router and enable it. It comes with a password/passphrase to protect your network, and it has encryption so nobody outside the network can sniff your traffic.

Comment: I use WPA2 but I haven't knew that this option encrypt traffic from laptop to router.

Comment: You can also use [ssh tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WPA2, you are encrypting the traffic between your wireless devices and the wireless AP (typically built into a router).

There are two implementations of WPA2, but I will assume you are using the pre shared key version.

It introduces encryption using [this method](http://etutorials.org/shared/images/tutorials/tutorial_57/08fig17.gif).  It is generally acceptable for home network solutions, but not enterprises.  The reason for this, is because, with WPA2-PSK, if you know the passphrase for the network, it is possible to decrypt other people's traffic who are talking to the same SSID (wireless name), as long as they are able to capture that device's 4-way handshake (mostly trivial unless there is 802.11w involved).

WPA2-PSK is currently considered "strong" and has no known major faults.  However, it should be noted that the amount of security is derived from the strength of the password you use.
If you use a password of "abc123", your network is much less secure (from dictionary/brute force attacks) than if your password is "a0fj9sd09fj#J)()F9".